# Perl export to child modules

Tags: perl, moose

I have this parent module MyApp.pm:

```
package MyApp;
use Moose;
use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(msg);
sub msg {
    print "Hello msg\n";
}
1;
```

which is inherited by this child module MyApp2.pm:

```
package MyApp2;
use Moose;
extends qw(MyApp);
1;
```

and when used in the App.cgi script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MyApp2;
msg();
```

I get error message:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::msg called at App.cgi line 3.
```

So the exported function does not work in the child class MyApp2 but works only if I use "use MyApp" instead of "use MyApp2". I assume the exported function should be accessible to the child modules also which is extending the parent class. What I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found for my request:

```
package MyApp;
use Moose;
use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(msg);

sub import {
my ($class, @args) = @_;
    my $caller = $class.'::';
    {
        no strict 'refs';
        @{$caller.'EXPORT'} = @EXPORT;
        foreach my $sub (@EXPORT) {
            next if (*{"$caller$sub"}{CODE});
            *{"$caller$sub"} = \*{$sub};
        }
    }
    goto &Exporter::import;
}

sub msg {
    print "Hello msg MyApp\n";
}
1;
```

The idea here is I export all the contents of the "@EXPORT" array into the child module, only add none existent subs so will not overwrite any methods in the child class.

In this example above, this exports from MyApp to the child MyApp2.

This works for my own needs.

Answer (score 5):

Inheritance only changes how *method calls* are handled; function calls or variable accesses (like `our @EXPORT`) are not affected.

Instead of exporting a function, you could use it as a method:

```
use MyApp2;

MyApp2->msg;
```

but in this case, it would be cleaner to explicitly load `MyApp` in order to import the `msg` function, and to additionally load `MyApp2` in order to load this class.

```
use MyApp;
use MyApp2;

msg;
```

It is generally advisable for a module to either be object oriented or to offer an interface via exported functions, but not do both.

Comment: So no way to export to the child modules? I want to build my own small framework with one main module and all sub modules extend this module so all the application share the same environment and what I want to do is exported functions in the main module be available to all child module. Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible - instead of `extends qw(MyApp);` write `use MyApp; extends qw(MyApp);`. This is very, **very** inadvisable though. This kind of thing is likely to trip you up further down the road unless you're guru enough. And anyone who needed to ask how to do this is not guru enough.